# Recent posts on homepage showing full post not excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I have managed to get recent posts showing on my homepage which is working well. They only problem i have is that the full post and not the excerpt is showing.

```
<div id="home-news-container">

<?php query_posts('cat=#&posts_per_page=3'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="home-post-container">

          <div class="home-post-thumb">
              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large_wide'); ?>
              </a>
          </div>

          <div class="home-post-copy">
                  <h4>
                      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                           <?php the_title(); ?>
                      </a>
                 </h4>
                 <h5>
                      <?php the_date(); ?>
                  </h5>
              <?php echo the_excerpt(); ?>

              <div class="home-news-readmore">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">read more</a>
              </div>        
        </div>

   </div> <!-- end home-post-container -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

          <div class="home-news-readmore news-extra">
               <a href="">more news</a>
          </div>  

</div> <!--- end home-post-container -->
```

I don't understand what the problem is to be honest. I created a new full width template for the homepage which i thought might be causing it but its not. Bit stumped to be honest. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What does `the_excerpt()` function look like?

Comment: I thought the excerpt function should display a bit of the post. I think wordpress is 55 words but i might be wrong

Comment: Possibly an unrelated question; but do you need `echo the_excerpt()`? You don't have an echo in `the_date()`, or `the_title()`, so you probably don't need one for `the_excerpt()`.

Comment: Just tried removing it but it didn't change anything, good shout though as i don't need it.

Comment: I am no WordPress expert but you should definitely read the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) and tell me a fact rather than a thought.

Comment: @user3115441 -  looking at the docs, it will provide an automatic excerpt of 55 words if you've not provided one in the excerpt field in the post. Can you confirm that your posts are longer than 55 words? It might be worth adding something into the except field for a post, too, to see if that appears - just the word 'test' or somesuch.

Comment: I have read the documentation. It displays an excerpt as i said. The reason i said i thought was because it isn't doing that. Do you have anything useful to add? <- in reply to user2191572

Comment: Posts are definitely over 55 words. There is no longer and excerpt field in wordpress that i can see (i am using 3.8)

Comment: so i solved it, not sure its the best way to do it but here it is:

`<?php
$content = get_the_excerpt();
echo wp_trim_words( $content , '30' ); ?>`

hopefully useful to someone

Answer (score 0):

Use [wp_get_recent_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) to get recent post 
Use [substr](http://php.net/substr) to display some limeted character of post character

```
<?php 
$args = array (
            'numberposts' => 3,
            'post_type' => 'your post type name'
            );
// the query
$recent_posts = new wp_get_recent_posts( $args ); 

foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
        echo substr($recent["post_content"],0,100);
    }
?>
```